# Docker Image Issue - platform_machine != "arm64" or platform_system != "Darwin"

Tags: pandas, image, dockerfile, apk

I am trying to build an image for supporting "`apk add --update --no-cache curl bash curl py3-pip vault`"

And when I do a "`pip3 install -r requirements.txt`" to install "pandas==1.3.3". I have tried the base image for `python3.9-apline` but it succeed on passing the apk command but failed on installing pandas with the following same error. Do we have any suggestions on which base image I should use?

````
182 Downloading pandas-1.3.3.tar.gz (4.7 MB)
183 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4.7/4.7 MB 65.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
184 Installing build dependencies: started
185 Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
186 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
187 
188 × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
189 │ exit code: 1
190 ╰─> [330 lines of output]
191 Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and (platform_machine != "arm64" or platform_system != "Darwin") and platform_machine != "aarch64"' don't match your environment
192 Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.9" and (platform_machine != "arm64" or platform_system != "Darwin") and platform_machine != "aarch64"' don't match your environment
193 Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environment
194 Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environment
195 Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine == "arm64" and platform_system == "Darwin"' don't match your environment
196 Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and platform_machine == "arm64" and platform_system == "Darwin"' don't matc```
````

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/17807#issuecomment-946975125